# Mercurial - Files nog showing on server (ls command)

Tags: java, mercurial, jenkins

I'm trying to setup a java buildserver with jenkins,maven and mercurial. Now my mercurial server is working i can push, pull and commit. Running the command 'hg serve' on the server allows me to see commits from my clients. But when i go manually into the repository (cd in server-terminal) and do an 'ls' command i can't see any file. When i clone the repository onto a new client i DO recieve the files pushed by the other clients.

This is somewhat strange behaviour. Does anyone recognize this? What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the command: hg update
fixed the problem. I can now see my folder